# Storing array of objects in mysql from Js but got empty objects

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, vue.js

I'am storing an array of objects from vuejs to mysql text field (laravel for the back-end) :

```
// her's the array
reponse:[
            {choix1:"", estBon:false},
            {choix2:"", estBon:false},
            {choix3:"", estBon:false},
        ],
```

I load the data in the array and do a post request to store the objects:

```
// chrome inspector result after loading data
3) [{…}, {…}, {…}, choix1: (...), choix2: (...), choix3: (...), estBon: (...), __ob__: Observer]
choix1: "t"
choix2: "tt"
choix3: "ttt"
estBon: "choix1"
```

So in my post request I pass the object like that:

```
reponse: JSON.stringify(this.reponse)
```

and with the coroller in laravel I save it.

But the result in my table is an empty JSON like that :

```
[{"choix1":"","estBon":false},{"choix2":"","estBon":false},{"choix3":"","estBon":false}]
```

Comment: @charlietfl  no, I'am supposed to have : [{"choix1":"t","estBon":choix1},{"choix2":"tt","estBon":false},{"choix3":"ttt","estBon":false}]

Comment: You are going to need to do some basic debugging. Use dev tools network to verify that what is sent is what you expect. Do some debugging in laravel to see if what is received is what you expect. There simply isn't enough known here considering the number of steps involved to get it from vue app to database